# Import error despite __init__.py exists in the folder that contains the target module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pythonpath

I have the following directory structure inside a `virtualenv`:

```
/dir_a/dir_b/__init__.py
/dir_a/dir_b/module_1.py
/dir_a/dir_b/module_2.py
/dir_a/dir_c/__init__.py
/dir_a/dir_c/module_3.py
/dir_a/__init__.py
/dir_a/module_4.py
```

Inside `module_4.py`, I can successfully import `module_1.py`, `module_2.py` and `module_3.py`. On the other hand, I cannot import `module_4.py` within `module_3.py` (e.g. `import dir_a.module_4`). It complains: "No module named dir_a.module_4"

What am I missing here? Do I need to mess with PYTHONPATH of my `virtualenv` here? If so, why is the import of `module_1.py`, `module_2.py` and `module_3.py` all fine without touching PYTHONPATH?

Comment: A side issue here is that having sub projects `dir_b` and `dir_c` should mean that they might depend on each other, but never on anything above themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not mess with `PYTHONPATH` in this case. I think what you need is called [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). In your specific case, to import `module_4` from a submodule like `module_3` you need:

```
from .. import module_4
```

I will try to recreate a contrived example just to try to explain myself:

module_1.py:

```
# import sibling submodule
print 'module_1'
from . import module_2
```

module_2.py:

```
print 'module_2'
```

module_3.py:

```
# import parent module
print 'module_3'
from .. import module_4
```

module_4.py:

```
# import child submodule
print 'module_4'
import dir_b.module_1
```

And an extra bonus special module that will transitively import all the others. Create a `module_5.py` inside package `dir_a` next to `module_4`.

module_5.py:

```
print 'module_5'
import dir_c.module_3
```

Now, from the `dir_a` parent folder you can see what happens when run a different modules/submodules:

```
$ python -m dir_a.module_4
module_4
module_1
module_2

$ python -m dir_a.dir_c.module_3
module_3
module_4
module_1

$ python -m dir_a.module_5
module_5
module_3
module_4
module_1
module_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it, but `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Comment: Relative imports only works inside packages. Assuming `dir_a` is the package name and `dir_c` is a sub-package, you can try `python -m dir_a.dir_c.module_3` from the directory containing `dir_a` package.